# Creating image of layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to create image of layout?  I have a GridView composed of 25 ImageViews. I want save GridView as an image and display it later on ImageView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

this will create an image of the view

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {   
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( 
        v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);           
         Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
         v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
         v.draw(c);   
      return b;
     }
```

pass it your layout, and save the returned bitmap as a file somewhere.

Comment: The layout params width and height were both -1 for me, so instead I used v.getWidth() and v.getHeight() and I didn't need the v.layout() call. Otherwise, this worked like a charm!